# Gaussian fit with two variables

Tags: fitting

If I have an expression where two unknown parameters and a certain range of one parameter are present then how I can get best fitted values of such two parameters by varying this range?

Answer (score 1):

You should really provide some of your attempt first, and your data would be useful. But this is how I do it.

`GaussianFunction = A/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] \[Sigma]^2] Exp[-(1/2) ((x - x0)/\[Sigma])^2]`

Then using `NonlinearModelFit[...]`

`GaussianFit = NonlinearModelFit[YourData,GaussianFunction ,{\[Sigma], x0},x]`

You can get the results from `GaussianFit["BestFitParameters"]` and plot the result as `Plot[GaussianFit[x],{x,xMin,xMax}]`

---

If you want to PLOT something rather than fit something which is what your comment suggests. Then:

`GaussianFunction[A_,\[Sigma]_,x_] = A/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] \[Sigma]^2] Exp[-(1/2) ((x - x0)/\[Sigma])^2]`
`Plot[GaussianFunction[1,1,x],{x,-10,10}]` For example.

Comment: M =.;
GF = 1.16*10^(-5);
MW = 80;
mt = 172.44;
x = (mt^2)/(MW^2);
C1 = (x/8)*((x - 6)/(x - 1) + ((3*x + 2)/(x - 1)^2)*Log[10, x]);
S1 = ((4*x - 11*x^2 + x^3)/(4*(1 - x)^2)) - (3/
      2)*(((Log[10, x])*x^3)/(1 - x)^3);
λ = 0.0396;
a = (C1/S1)*4;
b = (2*Sqrt[2]*3.14^2)/(GF*MW^2*S1);
ueq = M == ((1 + (a*U*Cos[Φ])/λ + (b*U^2*
          Cos[2 Φ])/λ^2)^2 + ((a*U*
          Sin[Φ])/λ + (b*U^2*
          Sin[2 Φ])/λ^2)^2)/0.8464

Comment: It is my data. Is it possible to draw any gaussian plot with these data? Actually I have a certain range of M and within this range I want to plot U Vs Phi and fro this graph I want to get an allowed range.

Comment: @PritiNayek This isn't data that is usable. You should have some data that is in two column format e.g. `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x2,y2},...}`. If you are talking about PLOTTING a Gaussian based on some known parameter values, then that is a different question and you are not fitting but just plotting.